# Interception of Installed Applications on android device

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I got the list of Package name & Label of installed application in database, Now I want to interception with installed application and database. Suppose any application delete from device then I want changes in Database. for that i am using broadcast receiver but my code not works.

```
PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
List < ApplicationInfo > list = getPackageManager().getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
for (int n = 0; n < list.size(); n++) {
    Apps.add(list.get(n).loadLabel(pm).toString());
    AppsP.add(list.get(n).packageName.toString());
    Log.w("Installed Applications", list.get(n).loadLabel(pm).toString());
    Log.w("Installed Applications Package", list.get(n).packageName.toString());


    ...
    In other class

    public class PackageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED)) {
                String added_package = intent.getData().toString();
                Log.i("PackageReceiver", "Package Added = " + added_package);

            } else if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED)) {
                String removed_package = intent.getData().toString();
                MyDBHelper DB = new MyDBHelper(context);
                Log.i("PackageReceiver", "Package removed = " + removed_package);
                DB.open();
                DB.deleteStmt = DB.db.compileStatement(QueryManager.ApplicationDelete);
                DB.deleteStmt.bindString(1, removed_package);
                DB.close();

            }
```

any help??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    intentAPP.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED);
            intentAPP.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_CHANGED);
            intentAPP.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_DATA_CLEARED);
            intentAPP.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_INSTALL);
            intentAPP.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED);
            intentAPP.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED);
            intentAPP.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_RESTARTED);

//for storing list in db

    for (int i = 0; i < AppsP.size() && i < Apps.size(); i++) {

                    DB.insertStmt.bindString(1, URLDecoder.decode(AppsP.get(i)));
                    DB.insertStmt.bindString(2, URLDecoder.decode(Apps.get(i)));
                    DB.insertStmt.bindString(3, 1 + "");
                    DB.insertStmt.bindString(4, "false");
                    DB.insertStmt.executeInsert();

                }

//adding package notification
if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED)) {
            String added_package = intent.getData().toString();
            Log.i("PackageReceiver", "Package Added = " + added_package);
            Intent Intent_add = new Intent();
            Intent_add.setClass(context, ServiceAppsAdd.class);
            Intent_add.putExtra("Package_Name", added_package.substring(8));
            Intent_add.putExtra("Status", status_new);
            context.startService(Intent_add);
```

Answer (score 3):

What, exactly are you trying to achieve?

If you are trying to prevent uninstallation or installation of apps, then I'm afraid you cannot do that. All you can do is request to be notified.

---

EDIT:

Have you also specified the intent-filter in your manifest? For example:

```
<manifest>
    ....
    <application>
        ....
        <receiver>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED">
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: No, I just want all installed application list in my db, and then make it real time interception between application (install/remove) with my db.

Comment: @nimit: how did you solve this.? Actually I am also stuck with this thing